# Add Authentification in .NET MAUI development?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-identity, maui

I an new to .NET MAUI and i am developing an App. But i don’t know where to start in implementing Authentification.
I have a ASP.NET Core WebApp running Identity already.

So What is the best approach to add Authentification in .NET MAUI development?

I have not tried anything

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: "best" is a matter of opinion and off-topic on SO.  And any answer would depend on the specific requirements of your app, for which you have provided no details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use your own web service for authentication, you can use `WebAuthenticator` to achieve it.

For more information, you can refer to: [Web authenticator | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/communication/authentication?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=ios)

Answer (score 0):

Actually best thing is to implement custom authentication service so there won't be any limitation in future.
However, MAUI got "Microsoft.Identity.Web" package to help you out.
Microsoft has provided better guide here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/mobile-apps/azure-mobile-apps/quickstarts/maui/authentication?pivots=vs2022-windows

Comment: Good, the explanation and the tutorial focuses on Azure Active Directory in accordance to the Azure Portal. But I already have my own Identification service, I can follow the code intergrating my own